# Normalizing file paths

Tags: .net, c#-2.0

I need to normalize a file path so that a part of the path can be matched via `String.StartsWith(...)`

Example:

- FullPath: C:/Common/Dir1/Dir2/file.txt
- CommonPath: C:\Common\

Although those two file paths are equivalent, the common part can't be matched via the method `String.StartsWith(...)`.

I now that the API method: `Path.NormalizePath(path, true);` can do the normalization, but unfortunately this method is **internal protected**!

What other opportunities do I have in order to get the file paths normalized? `Path.GetFullPath(...)` is probably on option, but only works for absolute file paths since it will add a prefix like: **C:/** for relative ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this work under .net 2.0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var path = @"C:/Common/Dir1/Dir2/file.txt";
            var canonicalPath = new Uri(path).LocalPath;

            Console.WriteLine(canonicalPath.StartsWith(@"C:\Common\"));

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```